# In Ruby on Rails, how do I assign a default value to a member_of member of an ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm new to ruby on rails, and I've inherited a codebase.  Right now I can't create a new user account in my application, when I try I get the following error:

NoMethodError in Users::RegistrationsController#create

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: /home/nathan/dev/legwork-core

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/contact.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Contact>'
app/models/user.rb:31:in`update_contact'

The calling code is here:

```
  searchable do
    string :category do
      self.category.name
    end
  end
```

Category is supposed to be an instance of ContactCategory, and what I think I need is to set self.category to the default if its nil.  I tried this to fix it:

```
  after_initialize :set_defaults

  def set_defaults
    self.category = ContactCategory.first if self.category.nil?
  end
```

I also tried:

```
  def after_initialize
    self.category = ContactCategory.first if self.category.nil?
  end
```

And I've tried:

```
  before_create :set_defaults

  def set_defaults
    self.category = ContactCategory.first if self.category.nil?
  end
```

Someone else has suggested putting this logic in before_save, but there is already a before_save that has this logic in it, that's where I saw what the author had intended to be the default in the first place.

UPDATE:

This question is silly now that I see what's wrong.  I was assuming that the assignment statement never ran because I assumed ContactCategory.first was also not nil.  Sadly, everything here is working as expected.  The moral of the story is:

All of the hooks I was using to set the default were working correctly. I would recommend using them to set a default using ActiveRecord.

Comment: can you show us the database structure? Describe table?  Currently you are using 'name' but it seems that that field doesn't exist.

Comment: That's the NoMethodError in Users::RegistrationsController#create
undefined method `name

Comment: The real problem is that the category is nil: `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: I thought it was category that wasn't being assigned, and so nil doesn't have a method called "name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use the `before_create` callback for setting default values and whatnot, but [here's the full list of ActiveRecord callbacks from the RoR API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). You'll notice `after_initialize` doesn't work like exactly its name suggests:

> Lastly an `after_find` and `after_initialize` callback is triggered for each object that is found and instantiated by a finder, with `after_initialize` being triggered after new objects are instantiated as well.

You probably want to use `before_save` or `before_create` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can't upvote it as I lack the reputation.  I just tried using before_callback and I had the same results.  There is already a before_save that has this logic in it, that's where I saw what the author had intended to be the default in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps you need to save down the Category ID instead? Something like `self.category_id = 1`?

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail?  Use an ID in the table and manually load the ContactCategory object somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure of how you have your relationships set up, but generally the foreign key is an ID. So if Something `has_one` Contact, then Something will have a field named `contact_id`, which Rails uses implicitly when you call `something.contact`.

Comment: When I experimented, it turns out all of the hooks are running the way you suggested they would.  The problem is that ContactCategory.first is also nil for some reason.

Comment: I see, so you just need to create a ContactCategory record! Wow, thinking to hard on that one

Comment: Yeah, it was in seeds.rb, but I hadn't noticed that the rake operation failed partway through for another reason.

Answer (score 0):

Also, remember that you can assign defaults (and ensure the field is never NULL) in the migration as well. [Here's an example from one of my own projects](https://github.com/sczizzo/Dhaka/blob/develop/db/migrate/20110626000738_add_roles_mask_to_users.rb):

```rb
class AddRolesMaskToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :roles_mask, :integer, :default => DEFAULT_ROLE, :null => false
  end
end
```